# How to prevent closing of combo box when an item is selected

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a ComboBox like the following and would like to prevent it closing when I click the header section (e.g. ***Administrators***).

[image]

I just tried the following code.

```
private void cmboName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cmboName.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            cmboName.DroppedDown = true;
            return;
        }
    }
```

But there is a shivering happens; first combo box will be closed and then opens.

Comment: What UI framework are you using? WinForms or WPF?

Comment: update the question with additional information don't just add it in the comments

Comment: Why do you want to prevent it from closing after chosing an item? It seems like a bad UI design

Comment: The good design would be to jump over the grouping items.

Comment: Because I do nothing with the header section. It is only used to categorize the fields. While clicking the header section I don't want to close the dropdown list.

Comment: re-think your design. what if you had two combo boxes, one labeled "User" and the other labeled "Administrator"? or use an icon in from of every item to represent admins/users. if you go ahead with this custom dropdown design, keep in mind that you will also have to support the behavior for keystrokes (Skip on arrow?, Enter, F4, ...)

Comment: Actually I like the design and prefer it to multiple boxes. What about three or four groups? (Guest or Public come to mind..)

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

What you need to do is suppress the message that tells the system that the `ComboBox` want to close the dropdown when it shouldn't.

To do that you need to create a subclass:

```
public partial class myComboBox : ComboBox
{
    public myComboBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private int direction = 0;  // where to jump when when doing keyboard selection
    private int lastIndex = -1;

    private void skip()
    {
        if (direction > 0 && (SelectedIndex + 1 < Items.Count))
            SelectedIndex += 1;
        else if (direction < 0 && (SelectedIndex - 1 >= 0))
            SelectedIndex -= 1;
        else SelectedIndex = lastIndex;

    }

    // optional, but you are owner-drawing anyway..
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pe);
    }

    // use your own logic to determine which entries can be selected!
    bool Invalid(int index)
    {
        return index < 0 ? true 
                         : (Items[index].ToString().StartsWith("X"));
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up) direction = -1;
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down) direction = 1;
        else direction = 0;
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x111) /*  WM_COMMAND */
        {
            if (((int)m.WParam >> 16) == 1)
            {
                if (Invalid(SelectedIndex))
                {
                    while (Invalid(SelectedIndex)) skip();  // skip invalid entries
                    m.Result = new IntPtr(1); // return success
                    return;                   // consume the message
                }
                lastIndex = SelectedIndex;
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

  }
}
```

Note that my test uses a simple check for the invalid/non-selectable grouping/header items. Instead of checking the content for being "X" you need to use a suitable check of your own! Probably the same condition you use to bold these items in the `ItemDraw` event.

Comment: The code in your selection changed event works same as that in my code. Is it possible to sustain the list view without any disturbance??

Comment: That is what I mean in my last sentence. I haven't tried it though; working with, presumably, WndProc is not my strong side.. Th code works fine when using the keyboard, though, just clicking on a wrong items causes the flicker..

Comment: ok..This looks fine with the key board. I am really glad to know that you are working on it...

Comment: See the new subclass in the update, which suppresses the flickerand included the keyboard selection skipping the invalid items

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to disable some items from selection.
Try this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
        }

 private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string itemText = comboBox1.GetItemText(comboBox1.SelectedItem);

            if ((itemText == "Admins") || (itemText == "Users"))            
                comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }

private void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            string itemText = comboBox1.GetItemText(comboBox1.Items[e.Index]);

            if ((itemText == "Admins") || (itemText == "Users"))
            {
                using (var f = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8, FontStyle.Bold))
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(itemText, f, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds);
            }
            else
            {
                e.DrawBackground();

                using (var f = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8, FontStyle.Regular))
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(itemText, f, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds);

                e.DrawFocusRectangle();
            }
        }
```

It is not what you want, but it is the next best thing.